# Getting error duplicate entry: android/support/annotation/ColorRes.class

Tags: java, android, android-studio, out-of-memory

I'm developing application in android studio. When I run my app in device, I was getting `.dex file cannot exceed 64k` error. So for this, I use `multiDexEnabled true` in build.gradle file. Now I am not getting this error but I'm getting

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':MyApp:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'
```

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/annotation/ColorRes.class`

Any help to solve this problem ? Here's my build.gradle file :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mouthshut"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        }
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    dexOptions {
        incremental true
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
        preDexLibraries = false
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

afterEvaluate {
    tasks.matching {
        it.name.startsWith('dex')
    }.each { dx ->
        if (dx.additionalParameters == null) {
            dx.additionalParameters = ['--multi-dex']
        } else {
            dx.additionalParameters += '--multi-dex'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':comnostra13exampleuniversalimageloaderHomeActivity')
    compile project(':nineoldandroid')
    compile project(':libraryActionbar')
    compile project(':pullToRefresh')
    compile project(':facebook')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.1.0'
    compile files('libs/AF-Android-SDK-v2.3.1.19.jar')
    compile files('libs/classes.jar')
    compile files('libs/CleverTapAndroidSDK-v1-20150903.jar')
    compile files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
    //compile 'com.github.adrian110288:LoadIndicators:83ce610325'
    compile project(':LoadIndicatorLibrary')
    //compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
}
```

Comment: some of your libraries are using duplicate code inside and avoid using plus when defining version like you did with play services

Comment: @VivekMishra but I cannot remove library..!!

Comment: find which library or jar creates duplicate entry , press ctrl+N  and search ColorRes.class

Comment: Three problems I see: 1) Why are you referencing jars directly? CleverTap and Youtube sdk are both available through online repositories. The rest too, probably. 2) what's the the 'classes.jar' dependency? makes no sense to me. 3) appcompat version should be the same as the compileSdk version. Why use appcomat v19 when compiling for v23?

Comment: @nitzanj  we were using eclipse before android studio. So whole project is migrated from eclipse. That's why adding jar files.

Comment: Well as @VivekMishra mentioned the error you see is related to dependencies, so as a first step I'd migrate  all of them. That alone may fix your problem.

Comment: @nitzanj I used ctrl+N and searched ColorRes file..I got android-support-v4.jar and support-annotation-23.1.1.jar has same ColorRes file. I cannot remove support-v4 file and not found the annotation jar so that i can remove it.